# What protocol is used to authenticate windows 10 machine against azure ad?

Tags: windows, azure, protocols

I want to learn how Windows AD works behind the scenes and here is first question.
What protocols is used to authenticate Windows 10 devices against Azure AD?

Comment: I mean Azure AD, not Windows AD

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article on Azure AD authentication protocols.  Essentially it breaks down to OAuth 2.0 and SAML 2.0 among others

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-protocols/

Versus Windows Active Directory which supports LDAP and ADSI among a few others.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961766.aspx

Comment: Please add the relevant part of the links to your answer.